# Green fluid on cabin filter

Tags: honda, accord, cabin-filter

During a routine oil change they found green fluid on the cabin air filter. We took it to Honda dealership and they looked at it and said they’ve never seen anything like that and felt it was nothing. My husband is going back there because I said it’s just not normal and the people who did the oil change set it look like coolant.What do you think it could be? The Honda Accord is a 2016 with 12,000 miles on it[image][image]

Honda said they could not find source. I have pic. Jiffy lube said it was green. Honda thinks it was blue and dried a blue green color. I am concerned because the car warranty is up in Feb but we only have 12k miles . Does the Honda diagnostic system test the heater core?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Honda uses blue coolant in their vehicles. Considering the year/mileage of the vehicle, I'd bet it's never been changed. It definitely warrants checking into thoroughly, but I doubt its coolant ... at least not coolant from your car.

Comment: Coolant has a pretty distinctive sweet smell.  Possible pollen from overhanging trees from where the car is parked?

Comment: Is the AC working ok? Green fluid sounds like UV-dyed PAG refrigerant lubricant to me.

Comment: Honda said they could not find source. I have pic.

Comment: Jiffy lube thought it was PAG fluid. Honda says no

Comment: Can you have a look at the evaporator fins too?

Comment: Windshield washer fluid going down the fresh air duct? Doesn’t look like UV dye to me.

Comment: Wait a moment. We're you there on site when this filter was removed? Or did they remove it and inform you later?